# I need help solving an integral expression

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis

I need help solving this problem.  I know that:
$$\int_{t_1}^{t_0}F(t)\space dt=\frac{t_0^2+t_1^2}{2t_0^2}$$
and I want to find F(t).  I tried taking the derivative and re-integrating:

```
D[(t0^2 + t^2)/(2*t0^2), t]
FullSimplify[Integrate[t/t0^2, {t, t1, t0}]]
```

but that didn't result in the desired expression:

`1/2 - t1^2/(2*t0^2)`

Can someone show me how to find $F(t)$?

Comment: If $t_1=t_0$, the expression on the left is necessarily zero. Did you check this for your right-hand side?

Answer (score 4):

I suspect that the right-hand side should be
$$
\frac{t_0^2-t_1^2}{2t_0^2},
$$
in which case

```
D[(t0^2 - t1^2)/(2 t0^2), t0] // Simplify
(* t1^2/t0^3 *)
```

works.  To check:

```
Integrate[t1^2/t0^3, {t0, t1, t}, Assumptions -> {t > t1 > 0}] /. t -> t0 // Together
(* (t0^2 - t1^2)/(2 t0^2) *)
```